# Uploading multiple files with Django

Tags: django, upload

How do I upload multiple files with Django?

Answer (score 11):

After a lot of pain I eventually got uploadify (http://www.uploadify.com/) working with django, but the problem wasn't really django's, but getting it to work with Apple Mac's;  browsers on that platform don't serve the cookies from within Flash; you need to set them manually:

So I include these in my render-to-reponse:

```
return render_to_response('files_upload.html', {
       'session_cookie_name': settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
       'session_key': request.session.session_key
```

And present them from uploadify via the configuration laid down in the template:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileInput').uploadify({
        'scriptData': {'{{session_cookie_name}}': '{{session_key}}'},
```

I've seen this done better with a decorator over the view, but this was the dirty hack I put in middleware to copy the POST into COOKIE before the session middleware runs to restore the session.

```
class FakeUploadCookieMiddleware(object):
   """TODO: replace the hardcoded url '/upload' with a 'reverse'."""
   def process_request(self, request):
       if request.path == '/upload/' \
           and request.POST.has_key(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME):
           request.COOKIES[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME] = \
               request.POST[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME]
           logging.debug('Faking the session cookie for an upload: %s', \
               request.POST[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME])
```

Comment: well, now this should definitely be placed somewhere on uploadify home page, struggled for some time with, til gave it up and used http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/06/14/swfupload-jquery-plugin/ (not with django though, but still, definitely cookies must have been a problem)

Comment: Did exactly what you have here and it still does not work - still error 403. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Someone has already created a multi-upload field that might serve your purposes.

http://scompt.com/archives/2007/11/03/multiple-file-uploads-in-django

Django has great support for building forms and working with file uploads. I would read through these articles to better understand how the multi-upload field code works.

1. [Django Docs - Forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs)
2. [Django Docs - File Uploads](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work, but I get a funky error. No matter what I upload I get: "No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form." Looking at the source, I can see that it's a TypeError being raised.

Comment: have u got enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: This is only 'multiple' in the sense that he's creating many `<input>` fields. Would be better to support HTML5's `multiple` attribute on a `<input type="file">`.