# Django - HTTP Uploading of Multiple Images

Tags: django, django-forms, django-uploads

I looked at this question:

[Uploading multiple files with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348669/uploading-multiple-files-with-django)

but it did not seem to help as I have issues regarding it:

1. I don't want to deal with flash sessions using SWF Upload and Uploadify because I need to do uploads that only authenticated users can do.
2. newforms are for older versions of django, I am using 1.3

Using Django, how can I have this HTML form structure:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="." method="post">
 <label for="id_image_1">Image 1</label>
 <input type="file" name="image[]" id="id_image_1" />

 <label for="id_image_2">Image 2</label>
 <input type="file" name="image[]" id="id_image_2" />
</form>
```

and handle it using a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed number of filefields, you could simply define a form with enough filefields, or add filefields programatically in a form's constructor. See the Django docs on [File Uploads](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/file-uploads/).

If you want some sort of dynamic functionality (a la gmail's "add another file"), then you could define a formset using a form with a single filefield.  Display a single form initially and when you want to add another, use a little javascript to produce the new form and update the formset's management form.  There are a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax) [of](http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/) [snippets](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1389/) [floating](http://www.brantsteen.com/blog/django-adding-inline-formset-rows-without-javascript/) around to help you do this, though they may need some tweaking.  See the Django docs on [File Uploads](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/file-uploads/) and [Formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/formsets/).

Another option may be to use a [custom widget and field](http://scompt.com/blog/archives/2007/11/03/multiple-file-uploads-in-django), though I have not reviewed or tried this.

On the off-chance you aren't aware, the name="image[]" scheme is PHP specific and has no special meaning in other languages, unless you reimplement it.

Answer (score 0):

newforms is what the current forms were called before 1.0. Furthermore, if you got your form validated, http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/, you'll have your files as a list (tuple, probably, but sequence anyway) in request.FILES['image'], so just do:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
       for f in request.FILES['image']:
           handle_uploaded_file(f)
```

You'll have to write handle_uploaded_file yourself, the URL explains how