# django uploadify 302 error with @user_passes_test decorator

Tags: django, uploadify

Hi I'm using Uploadify in one of my django applications. It works fine. But when I use the `@user_passes_test` decorator, uploadify is getting a Http 302 error. Only logged in users with a specific permission should be allowed to use the fileupload.

my view looks like this:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('cylebrations.can_multiupload'))
def myFileHandler(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for field_name in request.FILES:
            image=Image(gallery_id=gallery.id, image=request.FILES[field_name])
            image.save()
            return HttpResponse("ok", mimetype="text/plain")
    return render_to_response('gallery_upload.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

when I use something like following in the view instead of the decorator, I also get a 302 error.

```
if not request.user.has_perm('cylebrations.can_multiupload'):
    return HttpResponse("You can't upload.")
```

It looks like the view doesn't get the userinformation.
Is there any way to pass the neccessary user information through uploadifys `postData` setting? How can I use uploadify with django permissions?

Comment: Please clarify, what kind of test should the user pass? I guess only logged in users are allowed to use your uploadify script?

Comment: You're right only logged in users are allowed to use it. I edited the question.

Comment: Does the @login_required decorator work?

Comment: No, the @login_required also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a forum entry, that shows how it can be done: 
http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/7195/uploadify-3-0-beta-with-django/p1

It contains a link to [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348669/uploading-multiple-files-with-django) which might be helpful too.

Comment: I created a middleware and added the formData to my uploadify options. But I still get a Http404 error.

Comment: I edited my answer because I found some links. They are doing basically the same I proposed but it seems they already tested their solution